# Playwright authentication and closing context for each and every test

Tags: automated-tests, playwright

I have a series of Playwright tests that may require me to authenticate into different apps. I have a helpful function that allows me to simply pass a URL and it will set a browser context with a specific storage state. It looks like this:

```
export const visitWithAuth = async (browser: Browser, url: string) => {
  let storageFile = ''

  if (url.includes('myFirstSite')) {
    storageFile = FIRST_SITE_FILE
  } else if (url.includes('mySecondSite')) {
    storageFile = SECOND_SITE_FILE
  }

  if (!storageFile) {
    throw new Error('Invalid URL or no matching storage state found.')
  }

  const context = await browser.newContext({ storageState: storageFile })
  const page = await context.newPage()

  await page.goto(url)

  return { page, context }
}
```

So in the test, it'll look like this:

```
  test('make sure the thing works really good', async ({ browser }) => {
    const { page, context } = await visitWithAuth(browser, 'https://www.myfirstsite.com')
    await page.dostuff()
    await expect(page.otherstuff).toBeWhatever()
    await context.close()
  })
```

What I'm finding is that I need to manually ensure that I have `await context.close()` at the end of every single one of my tests. It seems that when test signatures uses the normal `test('make sure the thing works really good', async ({ page })`, there exists `after` hooks in the trace viewer that closes everything as needed.

Is there a way to simply set some kind of config so that any contexts are closed automatically after a test is done? I was hoping I could simply pass some new options with the call to `nextContext` or `newPage` but I don't see anything in the documentation.

FWIW, Playwright's documentation also mentions closing contexts manually in their example here: https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#testing-multiple-roles-together

Answer (score 0):

After some research it turns out that the best way to do this is through fixtures. Fixtures act similarly to a hook and allow for actions to happen before and after the test steps that happen in the actual test.

Here's a little code snippet/example that follows the original question:

```
type AuthFixtures = {
  myFirstSite: Page
  mySecondSite: Page
}

export const test = baseTest.extend<AuthFixtures>({
  myFirstSite: async ({ browser }, use) => {
    const { page: authorizedPage, context: authorizedContext } = await createAuthContext(browser, `${process.env.MY_FIRST_SITE_URL}`)
    await use(authorizedPage)
    await authorizedContext.close()
  },
  mySecondSite: async ({ browser }, use) => {
    const { page: authorizedPage, context: authorizedContext } = await createAuthContext(browser, `${process.env.MY_SECOND_SITE_URL}`)
    await use(authorizedPage)
    await authorizedContext.close()
  }
})
```

The function 'createAuthContext' is returning a page and context. That means we the call to `use(page)` aligns with what happens in the test steps, and in the fixture we can call `context.close()` without having to do it in the test itself. This means that we can write a test like this now:

```
  test('do some tests while authed into myFirstSite', async ({ myFirstSite: page }) => {
    page.doStuff()
  })
```

For any rubyists out there, `await use(page)` almost mimics what `yield` does in Ruby.